# Is there a way to iterate through 2D C++ vector to create XGDMatrix?

Tags: xgboost

I want to create an `XGDMatrix` from a C++ 2D vector. My data inputs are in a `vector<vector<float>>` and I do not want to convert them into a 2D float array to be able to use `XGDMatrixCreateFromMat` (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/include/xgboost/c_api.h#L177). Is there a way to use an iterator to the vector to construct `XGDMatrix`?

I was looking through the APIs in https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/include/xgboost/c_api.h and came across `XGDMatrixCreateFromDataIter` https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/include/xgboost/c_api.h#L12. But I do not know how to use it, can someone help with an example to use `XGDMatrixCreateFromDataIter`?

I want to load the data the same way in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45790765. However, instead of loading the data from a `float[][]`, I want to load it from `vector<vector<float>>` without converting the 2D vector to a 2D float array.